# Create link in popup.js and make it clickable in popup.html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have two variables in `popup.js`. I want put them together to an url , anyhow like

```
chrome.tabs.create({active: true, url: "https://"+savedApi+".myservice.com"+currentDomain});
```

and pass this url to `popup.html`, where it becomes clickable, like `<a id="link" target="_blank">link</a>` and opens in new tab.

How could it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass/add code(hyperlink in your case) to popup.html, make use of chrome.extension.getViews method which returns an array of the Window objects for each of the pages running inside the current extension which includes any popup pages, if defined and loaded. Then simply in the popup window add the hyperlink to the desired place.

For example here we add a hyperlink to a container having id as content:

```
var views = chrome.extension.getViews({ type: "popup" });
views[0].document.getElementById("content").innerHTML =
             '<a href="https://www.google.com">Link</a>';
```

This will add the hyperlink to popup.html.

Comment: With your code i'm a bit nearer to my goal - but still not there:) If i inspect `popup.html` with DevTools i already see `<div id="content"><a href="https://www.google.com>Link</a></div>` - but it isn't clickable from `popup.html`. I click it, i see it is clicked, but the link isn't opened in the new tab... Do you know, what could be missed there?

Comment: To open it in another tab edit the above code by this : views[0].document.getElementById("content").innerHTML =
             '<a href="#" onclick='open_tab();event.preventDefault();'>Link</a>';  , Then in the popup.js file only create function open_tab and add the following:              function open_tab()                                                                                                  {  chrome.tabs.create({active: true, url: "https://www.google.com"}); }

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have included popup.js in popup.html.

Use below code in your popup.js file to create anchor in the popup.html

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var anchorTag = document.createElement('a');
    anchorTag.setAttribute('href','https://"'+savedApi+'".myservice.com"'+currentDomain);
    anchorTag.setAttribute('target','_blank');
    anchorTag.innerText = "link text";
    document.body.appendChild(anchorTag); // change this line as you need
});
```

Comment: Yes, `popup.js` is included into `popup.html`. But, adding your code did nothing. DevTools inspection displays that `popup.html` still has just `<a id="link" target="_blank">link</a>` without `href` and `target` attributes and anchor.